# Basic Authentication is not working in Apache solr 8

Tags: solr, solr8

I working on the Apache solr (version 8) authentication, using basic authentication API. Using below security.json and placed in the $Solr_Home(/opt/solr/server). But still i am not getting authentication popup when I open the solr site

```
  {
    "authentication":{
       "blockUnknown": true,
       "class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
       "credentials":{"solr":"IV0EHq1OnNrj6gvRCwvFwTrZ1+z1oBbnQdiVC3otuq0= Ndd7LKvVB
AaZIF0QAVi1ekCfAJXr1GGfLtRUXhgrF8c="},
       "realm":"My Solr users",
       "forwardCredentials": false
      },

 "authorization":{
     "class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
     "permissions":[{"name":"security-edit","role":"admin"}],
      "user-role":{"solr":"admin"}
       }}
```

Comment: Hi please help me to fix this issue

Comment: Are you running your solr in cloud mode?

Comment: it is working fine. I kept the seurity.json in the proper folder /var/solr/data.

Comment: That does not answer my question. If you run in cloud mode, placing a file somewhere does not do anything. You need to upload the file into ZooKeeper who then in turn will propagate them across the cluster.

Comment: I am using standalone not cloud. so placed in proper location, it is fine.

Comment: /var/solr/data/ is the wrong place for the security.json. It needs to be placed alongside the solr.xml, usually in /opt/solr/ or /opt/solr/server/

Answer (score 4):

You should place the file in `/var/solr/data/` or where ever `solr.xml` is. and make sure the file name is `security.json`. Otherwise, Apache Solr won't recognize the file.

Comment: The Documentation is not really well in that point where you have to set configurations. But when you copy the file in the data folder it's working and the solr.xml is not located in that folder.